# SQL: Using case to change column value on 1 row only where value exists on 2 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that looks like so:

[image]

You'll notice that the `Text` column has two rows with the same value; `PERCENT ACHIEVED`. I want to change the `Text` value on row 2, to `PERCENT ACHIEVED MONTH` and keep row 5 as-is.

Using a `case` statement changes both rows. How do I change the value of just one row using SQL only?

I am using SQL Server 2016.

Current SQL to generate the dataset, looks like so

```
SELECT 
DimCompany.SID as CompanyFK,
DimBrand.SID as BrandFK,
DimSalesman.SID as SalesmanFK,
FLD01A as [Text],
FLD024 as [Value]
FROM OPENQUERY(SYSTEM21,'

select 
*
from CWAUL.SA080VMF

')

LEFT JOIN DimCompany ON DimCompany.CompanyCode = 'CW'
LEFT JOIN DimBrand ON DimBrand.BrandName = 'Group'
LEFT JOIN DimSalesman ON DimSalesman.SalesmanCode = 'R11'
```

Comment: Can you post your `UPDATE` statement?  You can't update a `SELECT` so we need to see what it is that you are trying to update.  You won't be able to update this data without adding a primary key column to the result set so that you can uniquely identify the row(s) to update.

Comment: Its not an `UPDATE` I am trying to achieve, sorry I should have been more specific. The code I posted is generating the dataset, and will be used to insert into another table (via SSIS). But before inserting I wanted to make sure their is a clear distinction between the `percent achieved` values - if that makes sense?

Comment: Based on your dataset, how do you know that the `PERCENT ACHIEVED` on row 2 is the percent achieved for the month? What if the data was ordered differently? Will the first percent achieved value always be the one for the month?

Comment: You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in your `SELECT` to give a unique row value.  Not sure if that'll be usable for when you actually are ready to update the rows.  How do you know that the 2nd row is the one you want to update?

Comment: @squillman using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `Partition` seems to have done the trick - thank-you sir! I had to change the name of the `percent achieved` year value, instead of month, but I can work with that:

`CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by FLD01A order by FLD01A) = 2 THEN 'PERCENT ACHIEVED YEAR' ELSE FLD01A END as [Text],`

Comment: @marc_s sorry, typo - meant 2016

Comment: `partition by FLD01A order by FLD01A` is essentially a random ordering within each partition. Tables do not have an inherent order, so you may get different results each time. Even if you don't, it may change in the future.

Comment: You're right - ordinarily this would be random. It just happens that my particular dataset will always be in that order, so for me it worked.